# Is there a way to print something inside an object to the screen using document.write();?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to create a simple weather application which seems to be simple. I learned basic HTTP requests and so far I have this:

```
(async () => {
    let res = await fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=5100572&appid=1a58f8347985ec27ec49faffd124cc51");

    res = await res.json();

    console.log(res);

    document.write(weather);

})();
```

This logs to the console perfectly, but not to the document. All it prints is [object Object]..... how do I make it print something inside the object? For example temp is inside the object. When I do

```
document.write(res[temp]);
```

It says that 'temp' is not defined. So can someone please help me with this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the resulting res object from the `fetch`, above:

```js
{
  coord: { lon: -74.3149, lat: 40.7959 },
  weather: [
    { id: 801, main: 'Clouds', description: 'few clouds', icon: '02n' }
  ],
  base: 'stations',
  main: {
    temp: 277.78,
    feels_like: 272,
    temp_min: 276.48,
    temp_max: 279.15,
    pressure: 1004,
    humidity: 52
  },
  visibility: 10000,
  wind: { speed: 4.63, deg: 280 },
  clouds: { all: 20 },
  dt: 1611267179,
  sys: {
    type: 1,
    id: 4940,
    country: 'US',
    sunrise: 1611231362,
    sunset: 1611266455
  },
  timezone: -18000,
  id: 5100572,
  name: 'Livingston',
  cod: 200
}
```

If you want to display the contents of the `weather` property, you can do this:

```js
document.write(JSON.stringify(res.weather));
```

That will produce the following:

```sh
[{"id":801,"main":"Clouds","description":"few clouds","icon":"02n"}]
```

Comment: Is there a way to only print the temp not the whole main?

Comment: @JakeS The value of temp is simply `res.main.temp`, so use `document.write(res.main.temp)`.

Answer (score 0):

Either `document.write(res.temp);` or `document.write(res["temp"]);`

```js
let res = {temp: 450}

document.write(res.temp)
document.write("   ")
document.write(res["temp"])
```

Comment: it still says temp is undefinded

Comment: @JakeS did you try `document.write(res["temp"]);` with quotes around temp? That was a typo on my part. If not, can you show what a console.log of the res object looks like?

Comment: Yeah it said temp was not defined. I got it to work by doing document.write(res.main.temp);